# Kibana : How to get Line graph to get percent usage?

Tags: kibana, metricbeat

I'm newbie with Kibana and I tried to get a line graph with CPU ressource (system or user) but values are in number type (between 0 and 1).

I want to multiply by 100 with a scripted field (painless language) but when I did :

`return doc['system.memory.used.pct'].value.multiply(100)`

or

`return 100 * doc['system.memory.used.pct'].value`

Values are completly wrong (for exemple 0.964 becomes 2.536, instead of 96.4)

Did I miss something ?

Here the screenshot of my visualization :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm slightly surprised that this doesn't work out of the box. If the values are really in percent (and the field ends in `.pct`), I think this should just work out of the box. See my example below:

[image]

**Update:**

And here is the same visualization you're using. I only have a single host, but this is just working out of the box:

[image]

This is the underlying data in Discover:

[image]

And here is the index pattern:

[image]

I'd especially make sure that the index pattern is the same — both data type and format.

Comment: I edit my question to show you my visualization. As you can see it's out of the box configuration.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I'd check the index pattern, since something seems to be wrong for you.

Comment: Thank you I see that in my index pattern that all my field have a type but no format (I don't know why). I set up a format to all my fields taht I have to use and it's works perfectly. Thanks again :)